# [internet], [connection] and [internet-connection]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

First of all, there are [91 questions tagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet+connection) with [internet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet)[connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connection) (both) that should be retagged with [internet-connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-connection).

Second, what's the difference between [internet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet) and [internet-connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-connection)? When would someone use one over the other? since it seems to me that every question/problem related to the internet and tagged with [internet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet) could also be tagged with [internet-connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-connection).

Comment: As for the first part, the usual applies: Manual retag all the way.

Comment: @slhck It's gonna take a while (and I also need to get the edits approved) but I've started anyway.

Comment: If someone is referring to the internet as in root name servers / domains / etc, they'd use the `internet` tag instead of `internet-connection` - I'd say keep those two separate. Also, what if someone is referencing the connection to a website, computer over LAN, etc? in reference to the `connection` tag?